# Error Cordova debug

Tags: cordova

I was trying an application with CORDOVA, is there a mistake how can I fix it?

Thank you all

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\devolper\Android\android-sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
```

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

```
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug FAILED


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.143 secs
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.packaging.PackagerException: java.util.zip.ZipException: i
  >   nvalid bit length repeat
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.
  Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':packageDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.packaging.PackagerException: java.util.zip.ZipException: i
  >   nvalid bit length repeat
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

Debug has always worked, today it is giving this problem

Answer (score 0):

Add xml namespace for phonegap `(xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0") to config.xml`

After adding :

```
<widget id="com.ionicframework.yourpackagename" 
version="0.0.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
```

or simply

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
```